# D3 v5: Line not being drawn for line graph, and ticks not showing up on y-axis

Tags: d3.js

Update, here is error message in console:
Error:  attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL21.654801022…".

I am sure this is a fairly simple d3 question, and I have looked at other answers but nothing posted seems to help, the ticks don't show up on the y-axis, but they work perfectly on x-axis. Additionally, this is supposed to be a line graph but the line is not being drawn.

Here is the code:

```
var margin = {top: 10, right: 40, bottom: 150, left: 70},
width = 760 - margin.left - margin.right,
height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; 

var w = width + margin.left + margin.right;
var h = height + margin.top + margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg") // this appends a new SVG element to body
    .attr("width", w) // set the width 
    .attr("height", h) // set the height
    .append("g") 
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// x scale will handle time
var xScale = d3.scaleTime().range([0,width]);

// y scale will handle energy consumption values
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height,0]);

// Define X and Y AXIS
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale); 

var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y"); 


function rowConverter(data) {
    return {
        year : parseTime(data.year),
        value : +data.average // the + operator parses strings into numbers
    };
}

// line generator function
var line = d3.line()
    .curve(d3.curveBasis)
    .x(function(d) { return xScale(d.year); })
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.average); })


d3.csv("moreDummyData.csv",rowConverter).then(function(data){


yScale.domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d) {return d.average; })]); 

xScale.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; })); 


// Draw xAxis
svg.append("g") // add a new svg group element
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".25em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

// Draw yAxis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .selectAll("text")
    .attr("dx", "-.8em")
    .attr("dy", ".25em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end");

// add a title for the yAxis
svg.append("text") // add a new svg "text" element
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)") // turn it on its side
    // position the title in space
    .attr("y", -margin.left+20) 
    .attr("x", -margin.top-75)
    // give it text and style
    .text("ADD TITLE")
    .attr("font-family", "Times")
    .attr("font-size", "16px"); 

    svg.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
});
```

And this is what the output looks like with this code:

[code output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/02wg0.png)

Here's what the data looks like:

year,average

1971,30

1972,34

1973,29

1974,28

1975,31

1976,35

Comment: Have you checked your console? You should be getting some type of error. Update the post with it if you do.It could be a data issue at least in terms for the line not being drawn. Edit also post some sample data as well.That always helps with d3 questions.

Comment: thank you, added the update, error message is: Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "M0,NaNL21.654801022…".

Comment: Post your actual data. A few rows. Remove your block of code where you create the path, "svg.append("path).datum..". Then place it right after the block of code "svg.append("g").." or the block of code that "//add's a tiitle for the yAxis".

Comment: @JD333, okay, I updated the post with the data. I tried moving the svg.append("path") block but that didn't result in anything

Comment: Using jsfiddle would help others to help you. But, I think the problem is your data. I don't believe you can use timeParse for a year. Since year is just a number, you don't need to use timeParse. You could just follow how you're displaying the average. If you want to use dates, make sure you include at least a month.

Comment: @JD333 okay, I am unfamiliar with jsfiddle can you let me know how I can use that to help you? so I took out the parse time function and am just using + instead, but that made my x-axis really messed up. Do you know what it is that could be not allowing the tick marks on the y-axis to show up?

Comment: @JD333 when I hardcode the yscale domain, ticks show up, so I think I am loading the data wrong, I am not sure what it is that is wrong though

Comment: update! I solved the problem, I forked some old code to make this and I left the name value in the rowconverter function when it should have been year

Comment: So every time you do something check your console and try googling that error. jsfiddle is a website where you can showcase code so that others can start debugging the code themselves. The only other thought is I'm not sure about where you are using rowConverter. I see you are using it in d3.csv(). But, instead just use   data.forEach(function(d) {
        year = d.year;
        value = +d.average;
  }); inside your data.csv() returned function. Right before yScale.domain()